# How much memory does HashMap consume for N objects?

Tags: java, arrays, memory

In an interview, I was asked how much memory does HashMap take for N number of objects?

I know that Object header is 8 bytes or maybe 12 or maybe 16 bytes
If ArrayList then + 4 bytes because of int field
And a reference on an object is 4 bytes

Am i right?

Comment: `Am i right?` - No.

Comment: You ask for  HashMap but then reason using ArrayList - that doesn't fit. ArrayLists are not even used within HashMap. Just have a look at the source code and the variables that affect memory usage. Then calculate using the sizes you know or looked up. Alternatively create a small test program, get a memory dump of that program and analyze it.